# IntelliJ's Database Tool/Console is showing all timestamps with the seconds as 0 even when not

Tags: mysql, intellij-idea

I'm trying to view a table's rows with a timestamp column. All their times **should** be like this:

```
05:33:12
05:33:21
05:33:32
05:33:47
```

But when I do a `SELECT timestamp FROM MyTable;`, they show like the below in the results table:

```
05:33:00
05:33:00
05:33:00
05:33:00
```

Does anyone know if this is due to a setting? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: What version of mysql are you connecting to? Are you verifying via the mysql CLI that the values you expect actually are in the table?

Comment: @sisyphus Yes, in MySQL Workbench and the command line `mysql`, the seconds show properly. MySQL version: 5.5.48